# Каким образом с laravel используя mvc сделать форму без перезагрузки?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel

Никак не получается сделать форму без перезагрузки, выдает ошибку tokenmismatchexception, хотя в форме учел, пробовал и просто {{ csrf_field() }} такая же беда что делать? вот код:

```js
Это JS:
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contactform').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
 $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/sendmail',
            data: $('#contactform').serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
Это форма:
<form id="contactform" method="post" class="validateform">
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 field">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="* Введите ваше имя" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 field">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="* Введите ваш email" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 field">
            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="* Введите тему сообщения" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 margintop10 field">
            <textarea rows="12" name="message" class="input-block-level" placeholder="* Ваше сообщение..." required></textarea>
            <p>
                <button class="btn btn-theme margintop10 pull-left" type="submit">Отправить</button>
                <span class="pull-right margintop20">* Заполните, пожалуйста, все обязательные поля!</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

Это роут:

Route::post('/sendmail', 'AjaxController@send');

A это контроллер:

<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

Comment: Пробовал заменить на гет заместо пост, страница просто перезагружается

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" class="validateform">
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="row">
...
```

Должно быть

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" class="validateform">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
...
```

**csrf_field()** вернет вам hidden поле, а вы в своем примере пытаетесь вставить мета-тег в форму

Answer (score 0):

Делаете все верно, однако

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Должен быть в head документа, возможно он у вас уже есть в Layout.